# Clarification on my deleted question

Tags: support

I asked a question here https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/126409/is-this-mobile-app-a-scam and it was deleted. No explanation was given. There were following comments present on the question, but since there is no indication that commenters where the same people who deleted the question it may or may not be the reason for deletion:

- This is seems to be a spam question affiliated with the owners of the site. Should be deleted
- I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be spam to promote the site - note that it 'asks the question' and closes by saying 'it seems pretty good for beginners'.

If this is indeed the reason, then I ask for the question to be undeleted because this reason is false. Also happy for any more tips than at https://money.stackexchange.com/help to improve the question.

It feels pretty bad to be groundlessly accused of something that you did not even think of doing. Here is my [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/106688/andrew-savinykh?tab=reputation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question was closed by 5 normal close votes, downvoted, and spam-flagged, all by normal users. I did check out your profile and decided not to validate the spam flag, but it didn't really seem like the question would be successful in its current form so it was better to just delete it.

I don't mind undeleting it if you'd like, but you'd still need the community to reopen it before you could get an answer. The comments you received give some sense of why people perceive it negatively.

Comment: Thank you it sounds reasonable. Someone I know sent me a referral link to this app (which I was careful not to include in the post), this was unsolicited, but since I know the person I'm sure that they had best intentions in mind. So I was wondering how safe that is, and if I or that person might be in danger of being scammed. Some scams work like "recruit a friend". I thought it would be a useful question for community. But if not, I think I got my answer anyway, from the helpful person who commented on my question first. So thank them.

Comment: I think I should take this as a life achievement. Never ever thought that I'd get my question deleted as spam.

Comment: :-) And sorry for your experience. I think probably with different wording you wouldn't have triggered people's spam-sense. Unfortunately we do get quite a few "product placement" type of spams.

Comment: And.  The way their website talks about “access to Stocks“ almost implies that there are parts of the world where it’s more difficult to trade US stocks. Maybe I am reading too much into this. In the US many of our brokers already charged no fee  so no matter how legitimate this company is, there is no motivation to open an account with them versus a company that has been in business for many decades.